# ORACLE query help regarding datetime

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Hi i'm having trouble with my query i'm suppose to get values by two datetime conditions as so:

```
 select * 
from cns_concerto_projects 
where SST_CREATION_DATE> TO_DATE('02/27/2010 16:07:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MM:SS') 
AND SST_MODIFIED_DATE > TO_DATE('03/26/2010 11:42:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy  HH24:MM:SS') < sysdate
```

could you please assist to correct this issue.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it in following way:

```
select * from cns_concerto_projects 
where SST_CREATION_DATE > TO_DATE('02/27/2010 16:07:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MM:SS') 
AND 
(SST_MODIFIED_DATE > TO_DATE('03/26/2010 11:42:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MM:SS') And SST_MODIFIED_DATE < sysdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your last line in the `where`.

You need to use `between` if you want to search a range.

So instead of this:

```
SST_MODIFIED_DATE > TO_DATE('03/26/2010 11:42:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MM:SS') < sysdate
```

Use this:

```
select *
from   cns_concerto_projects
where  SST_CREATION_DATE > TO_DATE('02/27/2010 16:07:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
AND    SST_MODIFIED_DATE between TO_DATE('03/26/2010 11:42:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and sysdate
```

Also, you have to use `mi` for minutes, instead of `mm`.

If you want to remove the `between` use this:

```
select *
from   cns_concerto_projects
where  SST_CREATION_DATE >  TO_DATE('02/27/2010 16:07:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
AND    SST_MODIFIED_DATE >= TO_DATE('03/26/2010 11:42:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
AND    SST_MODIFIED_DATE <=  sysdate
```

Comment: Still incorrect. Have a look at the second parameter of to_date functions

Comment: Using between on date time fields is often a bad idea.  Minus 1.

Comment: Bad idea because of the confusion it brings into understanding what is included. You really do not know without consulting the manual if it is a <= b <= c or a < b < c or a <= b < c or a < b <= c

Comment: I misread the question.  The keyword between does not seem to be applicable anywhere in this case.  In other cases, going for where something between DateA and DateB could cause you to miss records that happened on DateB, if the values include the time of day.

Comment: @DanBracuk: still don't entirely understand you. I got the point of the confusion, but why is between not applicable? The last where clause compares one date to two values.

Comment: @Yotam707: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that SST_MODIFIED_DATE will be greater than SST_CREATION_DATE always, then you can skip the first condition, as follows:

```
select * 
from cns_concerto_projects 
where SST_MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('03/26/2010 11:42:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') AND sysdate;
```

Here's the version without using BETWEEN:

```
select * 
from cns_concerto_projects 
where SST_MODIFIED_DATE >= TO_DATE('03/26/2010 11:42:07', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
AND SST_MODIFIED_DATE <= sysdate;
```

Comment: Maybe I'll correct the myself The dates I wrote was not intended to be a range but a two condition query for dates

Comment: @Yotam707 What are your two datetime conditions?